# cmake: define order of link flags

Tags: linker, cmake, flags

I am new to cmake. I need to link some additional libraries so I used

```
   CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=-lmymalloc -Wl,--wrap,malloc
```

The problem is that -lmymalloc is listed as the first argument of the linker flags in the generated Makefile, then several others follow (which seem to be defined in another way by cmake). I need to move it to the end of the listed flags, otherwise it will not link. How can I do that?

Comment: have you tried `target_link_libraries(${your_target} mymalloc)` ?

Comment: @AndreyKamaev `target_link_libraries()` doesn't respect the appearance order of the libraries added.

Comment: out of curiosity, why won't it link unless it's at the end?